# How to set a timer for autorefresh jpanel or jtable

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, timer, jtable

How to autorefresh a Jpanel or Jtable every 5sec while the Jframe is still visible? so that when I update the database the Jtable's content will update also

```
public static void refreshPanelItemTable(){
 int delay = 2000; //milliseconds
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
             MainFramePanels.itemTable.revalidate();
         }
    };
     new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
}
```

is this right?

Comment: wrong question: all update will be automatic, provided the _model_ fires the appropriate events :-) If it doesn't, something is wrong in your code, needs fixing ..

Answer (score 1):

Use a swing timer. In the action listener for the timer, check if the database has changed. If it has, start a new thread to load the database into the table.

Comment: -1 no need for manual updates, provided the model complies to its contract

Comment: Well, the model, AKA database, has no such contract

Comment: How can the tableModel find out about the database, other than a manual update?

Comment: implement it to poll the database?

Comment: Periodically? That is my point: you will need to put a periodic update somewhere, because I am assuming that this database, like most databases, doesn't have a capability to add listeners for changed data.

Comment: Anyway, you probably mean the correct thingy: some controller has to either listen to changes in the database or be notified if the db supports such and update the model as needed - you might consider being a bit clearer about it, especially in light of the OP being on the completely wrong track (manually updating the _view_)

Comment: I don't want to be judge, flamewar ---> 1. disagree I'm against pools, not pooling, its for hard, realtime, profesional application, with optimizations on both sides, something about refresh on 5secs period, 2. +++ agreee but is job exactly for XxxTableModel (for basic I/O by refering whole model, rather than loop inside, compare, setValueAt)

Comment: @tbodt most of databses engines (excluding embeded, true is that part of them) has (by default non free) those notifiers,  sure intentionally forgot about db2

Answer (score -1):

The way you are going to do this bit wrong.  You have to use timer class and refresh your sql query. You do not need the refresh the jpanel. just try following..

```
long delay = 15 * 1000;
LoopTask task = new LoopTask();
Timer timer = new Timer("TaskName"); 

public void start() {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = new Timer("TaskName");
    Date executionDate = new Date();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, executionDate, delay);
}  

private class LoopTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        refreshSQL();
    }
}
DefaultTableModel dtm=null;  
Vector v=null;
public void refreshSQL() {
 try {
  dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            ResultSet r = DB.dbConfig.search("your sql statement");
            while (r.next()) {
                v = new Vector();
                v.add(r.getString("aa"));
                dtm.addRow(v);

            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  }
```

Comment: correct track, with an important error: swing components/properties (including models) must be accessed on the EDT!

Comment: how can I loop this? while(JFRAME.visible==true)?

Comment: @kleopatra : I upvoted this, though missed that important part. Though is `Model` also needs to be updated on the EDT ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw yes, of course: the view is listening to its model, so guess what happens if the model is updated off the EDT :-)

Comment: call the start() method anywhere you want. Better you can use it in the psvm or after initcomponents(); . delay means the refresh time. 5 * 1000 means 5 seconds. As that add your value to delay.   thanks

Comment: -1 as an incentive to edit the answer and do the model update on the EDT :-) It's a major flaw not to ...

Comment: @kleopatra - "swing components/properties (including models) must be accessed on the EDT!" . can you explain me what you trying say. honestly I did not get what you are saying. what is "EDT"?

Comment: @kleopatra : So if OP wraps `dtm.addRow(v);` inside `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)`, that will do !!! I hope I am right :-)

Comment: @maXfenda : Please do look at the scope of `Vector`, its a resident of `while` loop alone, hence the statement after while will raise an error :(

Comment: what happened when you typed _swing EDT_ into the search field at the trailing upper edge of this page or clicked on the swing tag wiki :-) Concurrency in Swing is what you want to learn about.

Comment: As I got I did some modifications to the sample code. :) . @kleopatra - thanks for your kind words on last comments. I will keep in touch. :). hope this sample code will solve the problem of jhon.